# How do you remove all duplicate pairs from a list?

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, unique, distinct

I would like to add all the values of CY where the PY amounts are the same per PID

In other words: The PY of PID 1 and the PY of PID 4 are the same.
The PY of PID 2 and the PY of PID 5 are the same

```
Select
    [ID] ,a.[PY] ,a.[CY] ,a.[LAT] ,a.[LON] Into #tempa
        From MyTable as a
            INNER JOIN MyTable as b on a.PY = b.PY and a.ID <> b.ID

Select
    Convert (varchar, LAT) + ', ' + convert (varchar, LON) as 'Combined', 
    SUM(CY) as Total ,COUNT(ID) as [Count] Into #tempb
        From #tempa
            Group by Convert (varchar, LAT) + ', ' + convert (varchar, LON)
            Having COUNT(ID) < 2

Select
    SUM(Total) as [Total]
        From #tempb
```

How can I only add the CY values of ID 1, 4 and 5?

Comment: How come you want the ID 1 row instead of 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove rows 2 and 3 pretty easily:

```
select *
from insurance i
where not exists (select 1
                  from insurance i2
                  where i2.location_pair = i.location_pair and i2.pid <> i.pid
                 );
```

Based on your description, I think you want to aggregate this by `py`:

```
select min(pid), py, sum(cy), min(location_pair)
from insurance i
where not exists (select 1
                  from insurance i2
                  where i2.location_pair = i.location_pair and i2.pid <> i.pid
                 )
group by py;
```

However, this does not return the results that you specify.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=8ecf6893a3a53e6cb813d78b98b88127) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * Into #temp2 From #temp t
Where Exists (
Select 1 From #temp t2
Where i2.PY = t.PY and t2.ID <> t.ID);
Select * Into #temp3 From #temp t
Where Not exists (
Select 1 From #Temp t2
Where t2.ID <> t.ID);

Select * From #temp2
Select * From #temp3

SELECT SUM(a.CY) as CY FROM #temp2 a
INNER JOIN #temp3 b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, edit your question and put this code there and then delete this post. If yes edit and mention that this is the answer to your question.